# Hiding a BottomNavigationView during a fragment transition

Tags: android, android-bottomnavigationview

I am creating an app using single Activity so on `main_activity` I set the `fragment` as `NavHostFragment` and on the bottom the `BottomNavigationView`.
In fragment A (first tab selected), If I click on button_1...navigate on a new fragment (A1). Of course inside fragment A1 I need to hide `BottomNavigationView` so on `main_activity` I am using `addOnDestinationChangedListener` to hide `BottomNavigationView`.

The problem is that if I want use a transition (enter, exit, popup_enter, popup_exit) the `BottomNavigationView` hide immediatly. (example 1 on image)

How can I do to have the same as example 2 on image?[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your 'NavHostFragment' below the 'BottomNavigationView'. So even if you were to delay hiding the `BottomNavigationView` the fragment transition would still happen behind it. So without changing your implementation completely it won't be possible to have the new fragment transition above the bottom `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: Yes, I have the `NavHostFragment` in the mainActivity...and in `DashboardActivity` I show a `BottomNavigationView`.
To solve this I found 2 solutions: 
1) in  `DashboardActivity` use a `FragmentLayout` as container and replace the child fragment on every click on `BottomNavigationView`. 
2) in `DashboardActivity` set another `NavHostFragment`